# Need to double click everything on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mouse

In my case for some reason I'm finding myself in need to click twice in almost every app (not always, a random effect).

So, why would I suddenly have to double-click everything on my Mac?

Also seeing some slight graphical issues when selecting and dragging.

I immediately thought either mouse or graphical card, therefore I:

1. Tested my keyboard and all good must be the mouse, I changed mouse and still nothing.
2. I restarted the computer and still nothing, same issues.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be the device (a Satechi) I use to connect the mouse to the MacBook. It was failing, not entirely just slightly therefore not easy to spot.

I found out when I decided to remove that Satechi device completely and use a bluetooth mouse which connected directly and worked perfectly.

I was really starting to worry due to a recent update or maybe this was a symptom of something much worse like a hack or something like that haha anyway, have a great day!